# Should I use the "Question posted as answer" comment when the question would be likely to be closed?

Tags: discussion, comments, review, new-users, vote-to-delete

Often, new users think SE is a forum and consequently post questions using the answer field (also, probably, because they can't comment.)

These "answers" are quite a common sight in the Low Quality Posts section of the review queue.

So, while recommending deletion, I often use the feature which automatically posts these comments:

[image]

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review

and

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different
>   question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also add a
>   bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough
>   reputation.
>   - From Review

So, these are obviously nice comments that will be helpful for new users learning about how SE works. However, what if the question the user posted as an "answer" is of such quality that it's likely to be closed? For example, it may be:

- Broad
- Opinion-based
- Unclear
- Already asked
- Off-topic

Should this automated feature then still be used?

What often happens is that the user then sees the comment and thinks a user typed it manually for their benefit. The comments even feature inviting links, leading straight to the page for asking questions.They may thus assume they have a suitable question, and then take the advice given in the comment and ask, only to (often) have the question closed. Not a good feeling. ("Hey, you guys deleted my other post and *told* me to ask it as a question! Now that I've *done* that, you're closing it!")

So, when I see such an "answer" that, if posted as a question, *I personally* would vote to close or think is likely to be closed, should I:

1. Select "No comment needed"?
2. Use the automatic comment feature but edit the comment to clarify matters to the user?
3. Select "No comment needed" and manually explain in a normal comment?

I'm thinking that even if the user asks, it isn't so bad? After all, it's the only way they can interact on the site. If it's a dupe, they will be shown the other one and the answer. If there is something else wrong with it, they can get help improving and editing it. Or at least learn *why* and how to ask a good question?

Another problem with engaging in extended discussion in the answer is that the answer can be deleted at any moment. At least if the user posts a question it may just be closed instead of deleted, in which case comments are still possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think I have *ever* seen a question posted as an answer that would be suitable as-is as a question in its own right (I may be wrong, but even so it would be very rare). If those comments were only useful in cases where the post would be an acceptable question then they'd be pretty much useless.

I understand your worry and manually adding further clarification in a comment certainly isn't a bad idea, but it isn't absolutely necessary. Adding too much instruction in a comment to a new users (often) first post isn't very welcoming either, and is only going to scare people away.

Too much and it'll just come across as...

> Hi new user! What you did was wrong, don't do that... what you should do is this and this. And this. This other thing would help... Oh and do this other thing while your at it (but please make sure you don't do this)...

Which sounds arrogant and is just going to frustrate.

There is already a "How to Ask" notice on the question asking page with links to relevant help pages. If there is a problem with new users posting low quality questions, this is the place to improve:

[image]

---

So yes—use the auto-comments, or manually comment. I understand the issue but comments aren't the place to address it. IMHO.